# Basic security group ports required to run AWS opsworks instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I was trying to create some instances in aws opsworks stack. I am performing this on secured vpc. Which is not default one. That VPC have internet connection. However I have been instructed to restrict sources to required inbound ports to specific address only not to 0.0.0.0/0. Generally the ports we are using - ssh, http and https. ssh is ok to restrict to vpc subnet. but I have problem with http and httpd.
I have some queries- 
 1. What are the minimal inbound ports required to run opsworks properly and what will be the source? Hence we are not using 0.0.0.0/0 
 2. Since my cookbook stored in s3 which is accessible inside vpc. what will be the minimal port required.
 3. I am not using Opsworks default security group. I am trying to use other security cookbook.
 4. I have seen Opsworks are using some cookbooks from [github.com](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks). If I restrict then will it fail.
 5. AWS said the following http and https source should be 0.0.0.0/0. [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/best-practices-groups.html)
 6. When I am restricting ec2 instances are booting up but opsworks it is showing "setting-up" does not show any log messages.

Kindly advise what are the essential inbound ports to be opened and static source required to run in production vpc.

Regards
Biswajit Das

Answer (score 0):

Chef client and solo in general require no inbound ports of any kind other than the usual ephemeral ports required for outbound TCP to function.

Comment: Thanks Noah. But somehow opsworks instances are somehow hanging at setup.. any clue? Btw here opsworks using chef zero

Comment: If you're still at SAP, ping me on Monday (same address as always) and I can take a look more directly :)

Comment: Sure. I added you.